# Ordinal parameter not bound: 7; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 7

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

Tengo esta consulta en Spring de la siguiente manera:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT pe.nombre, pe.dni, pg.recorrido, pg.comprobante, tp.nombre tipo, pe.grupo_id" + 
" FROM persona pe INNER JOIN pago pg ON pe.id=pg.persona_id INNER JOIN tipo_pago tp ON tp.id = pg.tipo_id"+ 
" WHERE pe.nombre LIKE '?1%'" + 
" AND pg.recorrido LIKE '?2%'" + 
" AND tp.nombre LIKE '?3%'"+ 
" AND pe.grupo_id LIKE '?4%'" + 
" AND pe.dni LIKE '?5%'"+ 
" AND pg.fecha_pago BETWEEN ?6 AND ?7", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Persona> filtradoPersonas(
@Param("nombre") String nombre, 
@Param("recorrido") String recorrido,
@Param("pago") String pago,
 @Param("grupo") String grupo, 
@Param("dni") String dni,
@Param("fechaInicial") LocalDate fechaInicial, 
@Param("fechaFinal") LocalDate fechaFinal);
```

Y no se porque me sale este error:
Ordinal parameter not bound: 7; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 7
Ya busque en muchas paginas y todavia no encuentro solución alguna

Comment: Dónde buscaste? A mí me aparece como [el primer resultado en google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958908/ordinal-parameter-not-bound-2-in-query-annotation)

Comment: Me fije esa respuesta y no funciona. Ya probe con las cosas de ese link

Comment: "Ya probé" no le dice nada a los demás, no tenemos cómo saber de qué forma usaste un recurso y qué error te dio. NO pongas a otros a adivinar si esperas que no suenen condescendientes; sólo están asumiendo que no has hecho lo que no dices que has hecho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se siente como que mezclas sintaxis para formas diferentes de JPA. Como que eso que dices de que buscaste mucho, no suena convincente.

Ya que tienes los `@Param` apuntándole al nombre del parámetro, los *placeholders* en la consulta deberían tener los nombres, no los ordinales. Le estás diciendo que use el String `nombre` para el parámetro `"nombre"`, pero tu consulta no tiene ese parámetro en ninguna parte; tiene un `?1`.

Si usas números, el método que estás anotando debe ser más simple porque la anotación @Query agarra los parámetros e intenta usarlos en el orden que los declaras: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT pe.nombre, pe.dni, pg.recorrido, pg.comprobante, tp.nombre tipo, pe.grupo_id" + 
" FROM persona pe INNER JOIN pago pg ON pe.id=pg.persona_id INNER JOIN tipo_pago tp ON tp.id = pg.tipo_id"+ 
" WHERE pe.nombre LIKE '?1%'" + 
" AND pg.recorrido LIKE '?2%'" + 
" AND tp.nombre LIKE '?3%'"+ 
" AND pe.grupo_id LIKE '?4%'" + 
" AND pe.dni LIKE '?5%'"+ 
" AND pg.fecha_pago BETWEEN ?6 AND ?7", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Persona> filtradoPersonas(
String nombre, 
String recorrido,
String pago,
String grupo, 
String dni,
LocalDate fechaInicial, 
LocalDate fechaFinal);
```

Si usas los ID de los parámetros, tu consulta cambiaría a:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT pe.nombre, pe.dni, pg.recorrido, pg.comprobante, tp.nombre tipo, pe.grupo_id" + 
" FROM persona pe INNER JOIN pago pg ON pe.id=pg.persona_id INNER JOIN tipo_pago tp ON tp.id = pg.tipo_id"+ 
" WHERE pe.nombre LIKE ':nombre%'" + 
" AND pg.recorrido LIKE ':recorrido%'" + 
" AND tp.nombre LIKE ':pago%'"+ 
" AND pe.grupo_id LIKE 'grupo%'" + 
" AND pe.dni LIKE ':dni%'"+ 
" AND pg.fecha_pago BETWEEN :fechaInicial AND :fechaFinal", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Persona> filtradoPersonas(
@Param("nombre") String nombre, 
@Param("recorrido") String recorrido,
@Param("pago") String pago,
 @Param("grupo") String grupo, 
@Param("dni") String dni,
@Param("fechaInicial") LocalDate fechaInicial, 
@Param("fechaFinal") LocalDate fechaFinal);
```

Comment: Ese era el problema Alfabravo! Muchas gracias. Soy nuevo utilizando Spring y no tenia idea que habia una diferencia entre el '?' y los :nombre, por ejemplo. Me habia costado encontrar el error porque en otros ejemplos no se utilizaba el @Param si no otra anotacion. Sin embargo tengo otro problema que no se si me podrás ayudar. Cuando ejecuto la petición, me retorna un array vacío Postman. Esto tendra que ver que estoy tratando de retornar un List<Persona> cuando en realidad el método retorna otro tipos de datos? Quisiera saber lo que retorna un nativeQuery con datos que no sean del repository